# 'Instagram Public Content Access' For Development

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

I'm trying to develop an web app which use "Hashtag Search API"

API url: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/hashtag-search

When i used this API, Facebook returns "(#10) To use 'Instagram Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Instagram Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review." message

I need this permission for development but Facebook requires me to get approved for using this permission

It's a kind of permanent loop

Any suggestion?

Comment: I've forget to mention. I've tried "User Access Token" and "Page Access Token". Both gives the same response

Comment: did you try getting it approved?

Comment: @luschn i'm trying to finish the development

Comment: Did you come up with a soluation?

Comment: @Peterhack i did not find a solution yet

Comment: Hello. Did you manage to get the App approved. I'm trying to get it approved but every time I cannot pass the screen cast phase. My app is Server-to-Server, no user login or authentication.

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the same problem. You need to add the permission manage_pages along with instagram_basic and then you can do hashtag searches in your test app.

Comment: Tried adding permisson `manage_pages` still not able to get the meta related Instagram media id

Comment: @NaveenRaghuveer you also need instagram_basic to get anything instagram related.

Answer (score -1):

You need to create an "Test app" for your app: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/test-apps/

Using the Test App, you can use the hashtag search API, which will allow you to develop your app. Then, you can submit it to Facebook and receive the final permission on the production app where all your users (not only your test users) will be able to use it.